# Milliseconds are removed from time when data collected using fluentd

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I am using fluentd as data collector. But milliseconds from time is getting removed. Can you please suggest a solution to keep milliseconds in generated output.

Time is getting parsed only when I specify logstash_format true. But because of this indices are getting created as 'Logstash**' even if I specify index name. If I don't specify 'logstash_format true ' then except time field everything is getting parsed.

Here is my fluentd configuration file,

```
<source> 
    type tail 
    tag json.nwdata 
    path /etc/td-agent/access.log 
    pos_file /etc/td-agent/access.log.pos 
    format json
    time_format %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%L
    read_from_head true 
    time_key time 
    include_time_key true
</source>   

<match json.**> 
  type elasticsearch
  logstash_format true 
  time_key time 
  flush_interval 10s # for testing 
  index_name jsonlog 
  type_name jsonlogtype
</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the milliseconds in your `time_format` parameter, either with this format (if the milliseconds are separated by a dot)

```
time_format %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%L
```

or this one (if the milliseconds are separated by a comma)

```
time_format %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S,%L
```

Comment: Hi I have modified my question. Parsed time does not contain milliseconds even if i specify millisecond in time format.

Comment: Then I guess it's because of this [open issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/461), unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) as of Aug 2015 doesn't support millisecond for time. Since a lot of people were asking about this feature, here's an on-going work available.

- https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/pull/653